# How to set an activity's layout background width to 100%

Tags: java, android

I am using this code to get the device background to be the background for my activity's layout.

```
final WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
final Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();

MyHome = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
MyHome.setBackgroundDrawable(wallpaperDrawable);
```

However I want to have the width of the background to be as that which is in the device's theme as show in this image here [image] the first image is my activity while the second image is my phone on screen lock. How to I achieve this?

Comment: try to setscale to center crop. May this will work

Comment: kindly provide me with the full code for doing that

Comment: Grid not support setScaleType() you need to find Alternative to do this.

Comment: how about using linearlayout and relative layout that I have used for other activieties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to setscale to center crop. Maybe this will work you

```
<FrameLayout  
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/my_image"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply `scaleType` to a background image. Instead, you can change the layout to include an ImageView as the background, and other elements as the foreground.

For example,

```
<FrameLayout  
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/the_man_in_the_coat_image"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <!-- ADD YOUR OTHER ELEMENTS -->

  </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to setscale to center crop. Maybe this will work you

```
<FrameLayout  
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  </LinearLayout>

  <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/image"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

</FrameLayout>
```

I hope this one help